# Synchronize code between two machines for pair programming?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-liveshare

What's a good way to live-sync code across two machines for pair programming?
By "live-sync" I mean allowing for concurrent edits, e.g. the Google Docs model.

In particular, my friend and I would like edit the same code while maintaining separate build / test / run environments.
So, we could theoretically use something like Dropbox to sync the code while maintaining local builds.
However, Dropbox wouldn't work if we were simultaneously editing the same file.

OTOH, Live Share lets us simultaneously edit the same code, but it doesn't let us keep our own build environments, because files only change on the machine of the Live Share host.
(Unless there's an option in Live Share to also sync all changes back to the guest machines, which I couldn't find.)

Thanks!

Edit: Looks like there's a feature request to make this possible with Live Share, but it's unclear if it's going to happen: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/live-share/issues/3524

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as there is still interest here I will share an imperfect way of handling this that I have used.  I set up an ftp server and then configured the  vscode SFTP plugin by Natizyskunk to access it.  I then also installed the Power Tools plugin by egomobile and wrote a cron script for it to run.  So then between the SFTP auto uploading to the server and the CRON job polling the server for changes I was able to sync files.   If there is interest in more specifics just let me know.

I am sure that without much difficulty someone more knowledgable than me could write a cron job that would work better than what I did.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'm wondering - how is this essentially different from using DropBox to sync the files?

Comment: well I haven't tried it but that might just work. Won't know until it's done.  Pretty much the same concept though.